# Image scaling IE vs. Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a 32bit, 96x96 transparent .png image that I am displaying in a page with a height of 24px to fit it in my header.  In Chrome this displays very nicely (clean edges and resolved), however, in IE9 it is completely distorted.

Do I need to bump the image size from 96x96 to get it to display correctly in IE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a default setting in ie9 (and I think ie7 and 8), but it actually has has a css solution:

```
img {
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

Otherwise it will default to using the "Nearest Neighbor" algorythm to downsample images.

Comment: There's a pretty good explanation of this here: http://mikekeran.com/other/image-scaling-in-internet-explorer

Comment: @Ben D: Interesting. Tried setting the img tag in my css and still no go.  I might have to resize the image.

Comment: @Ben D: My inheritance was messed up in the css.  This worked!  Thanks!

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but i have the same problem in IE11 vs chrome and this css isn't working, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you probably will need to resize it. The way the browser decides to scale images isn't under your control, I don't think.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that the size of the image is equal to the size of the container. You do not need to rely on browsers for re-sizing. In addition to rendering, there are performance issues with re-sizing.

Comment: I have it set to the same size outside of the header (just in the body) and it's still distorted.