# Difference in image quality between IE and other browsers

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

My images show exactly the way they are supposed to in browsers such as Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Once i open Internet explorer and see the results there it gives me quite a big difference.

This is chrome : 
[image: This is chrome :]

This is Internet explorer : [image]

The images are both 460 x 460 and the css styles added to the images are :

```
background: url(../../Icons/Sigma/Vernieuwen.png);
background-position: left center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
display: inline-block;
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
```

In chrome this resizing works fine but in IE it does not. Now all the information i found was that IE uses some kind of nearest neighbour method for the resizing and that you could fix this by changing some browsers settings.

I tried resizing the image in photoshop to 20 x 20 but the result remains the same.

My question: is there a way to give IE the same result as Chrome?

Comment: this is one reason why libraries such as fontawesome were built

Comment: I am using font awesome most of the time but the icons i am showing here are just an example since it happens with the logo aswell but the icons here give a better example of what IE does with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
img {
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690613/image-scaling-ie-vs-chrome)

Comment: I tried adding this but it does not give me any difference. Could it be because it is set as a background instead of a <img> ?

Answer (score 0):

you cant change that with css. only way is to use small image, resize this image to `20px x 20px` and it will work

Comment: As i sayd in my question : I tried resizing the image in photoshop to 20 x 20 but the result remains the same.

Comment: @NielsPeeren thats not true. try again, remove cache, or try to convert to svg